# Angular 4 cant pass null as parameter

Tags: angular, url-parameters

In my program i want to pass get with parameters. One of those parameters are null. But when i set this property to URLSearchParams it doesnt appers in final Url? Is this possible?

Here the object with parameters which i pass as parameters:

```
{zpm_id:112, tow_id:null}
```

And here part of my function:

```
public getDaneOkna(rodzaj: string, symbolOkna: string, parametry: any) {  
 let params = new URLSearchParams();
 Myheaders = new Headers();
 for (var key in parametry) {
      params.set(key, parametry[key]); 
    }

 return this._http.get(this.adresSerwera + '/dane/' + symbolOkna,
      {
        headers: Myheaders,
        search: params
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value == null, don't add it with params.set...

Comment: if (parametry[key] !== null){ //set key }

Comment: So how can i do this? When i add it like a normal obj i mean  
params['key']=value it doesnt work.

Comment: I mean when i have to add null as parametr ?

Comment: You don't set the data, so it will be null when you're receiving it

Answer (score 0):

Its generally suggested to avoid using null completely in typescript. Use 'undefined' instead.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/null.html

But if for some reason you ended up passing parametry as undefined, you won't be able to access any properties of it, so this

```
 parametry[key]
```

would generate an error, whereas this

```
 console.log(parametry)
```

Wouldn't generate an error, it would just print 'undefined'

Other commenters are right its best to avoid passing in an undefined parameter. If you must, checks inside the method for its existence would be wise...